# Yii framework - Simple passing variable from View to Controller action

Tags: php, variables, view, yii, controller

I am using Yii framework 1.1.14. All I want is to pass variable (for example `$var`) from View to specific action(for example `index`) in Controller (for example `VideoController`). I want my code to look as following:

```
<a href="<?php /* Here will be route to specific controllers 
                  action with variable $var which will be 
                  passing by this way */ 
         ?>"></a>
```

So after click on this link, user will be redirected to url of this specific action and inside this action, there will be accessible variable `$var`.
Is there simple way to do it by using Yii syntax? Or how it will looks like if I will want to pass multiple parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view:

```
<a href="
    <?php
        echo $this->createUrl('controller/action', array(
            'var' => $var,
            'var2' => $var2
        ));
     ?>">
</a>
```

Or

```
<?php 
    echo CHtml::link('link text', array(
        'controller/action', 
         'var' => $var,
         'var2' => $var2
    )); 
?>
```

In your controller:

```
public function actionAction($var, $var2)
{
    //Since the createUrl as generated a $_GET parameter
    // $var will be automatically set here if you put it
    // In the method parameters
}
```